# Tiling Matrix row by row

Tags: matlab

I want to repeat each row n times, for example:

```
A= [123
    456
    789];
```

so I want to have:

```
b=[123
   123
   123
   456
   456
   456
   789
   789
   789];
```

I have tried `repmat`:

```
B = repmat(A,3,1)
```

But this does not result in the `b` above...How do I do this?

Comment: You can repeat the indices of the rows you want to repeat.

Comment: this is not a question that includes facebook, please use correct tags

Comment: why are people downvoting this? You should at least leave a comment to say why you are downvoting!

Comment: @Vivi Agreed! It is not at all obvious why this question deserved a downvote. It is true the problem is fairly simple, but the OP clearly provided evidence that they had tried to solve it themselves. I've given the question a +1. In spite of its simplicity, it is worth noting the problem has generated two different approaches in the answers!

Answer (score 5):

For vectors, simply use `repmat` on the transpose, and expand:

```
A = [123;456;789];
A = repmat(A.', 3, 1);
A = A(:);
```

More generally, for any matrix/tensor, use `repmat` on the indices:

```
A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9 ];
A = A(repmat(1:end, 3, 1), :);
```

Or, based on Colin T Bowers' answer below, a much faster alternative of that is

```
A = A( ones(3,1) * (1:end), :);
```

which is a bit harder to read, so include a comment line describing what it does when you use this.

Also take a look at the Kronecker product:

```
A = kron(A, [1;1;1]);
```

which can be very useful at times.

Comment: I think you meant to include an `A = ` in that second line Rody :-)

Answer (score 5):

Rody has provided you with the `repmat` solution (+1), but I thought it was also worth pointing out that:

```
A = [123;456;789];
A = ones(N, 1) * A';
A = A(:);
```

will be close to an order of magnitude faster, since `repmat` isn't a particularly efficient function. A quick speed test over 10000 iterations yields:

```
Elapsed time is 0.206894 seconds %#repmat solution
Elapsed time is 0.024718 seconds %#My solution
```

A final point, I notice in the comments that @Maroun85 suggests using linear indexing. However, I can't see a clever way to construct the required index without a call to `repmat`, which brings us back to the original source of slow-down. Someone else might be able to come up with a clever way to construct the required index vector though.

**EDIT:** Rody has updated his answer to provide the aforementioned "clever way". :-)

Comment: +1 multiplying by ones is a very good alternative to `repmat`, however, it only works with vectors `A`

Comment: Good idea though, I've used it in my answer :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis No probs :-) I'm grateful actually, as I didn't know it was possible to use linear indexing in that way.